# Is there a way to speed up triggered abilities in MTG Arena?

Tags: magic-the-gathering-arena

I got my first Scute Swarm in MTG Areana, and tried building a deck to see how much damage I could get against Sparky.  But, processing 1000 triggers (which is only 10 lands coming into play...) takes about 5 minutes.  Is there a way to speed up this processing in the client?

I've googled, and it looks like this is a common problem, as of January 2020, wondering if anything has been fixed since?